# Is there a special symbol for instrumentation amplifier, to distinguish it from an opamp?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, diagram, symbol

Is there a special symbol for instrumentation amplifier, to distinguish it from an opamp? If I use the opamp symbol in a circuit diagram, it looks wrong, like it's missing components:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The simplest InAmps need a gain setting resistor and a reference pin like this: -

[image]

Now that doesn't look much like an op-amp to me. However, if it doesn't use a gain setting resistor (or maybe it's internally fixed) and, the reference pin is somehow internally dealt with you can use an op-amp symbol.

However, I don't believe there are any InAmps that can internally deal with the reference pin other than by connecting it to midrail and this requires a 0V connection: -

[image]

Normally the 0V connection on R3 would exit the chip on a pin.

You have to consider why this is so; An InAmp takes the difference in voltage levels between the two inputs, amplifies it by the gain factor and then references this amplified difference to (for want of better words) to a "reference pin".

This is what an InAmp does.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special symbol for InAmp.  It looks not unlike an OpAmp with connections for R<sub>gain</sub> and V<sub>ref</sub>.

[image]

(This drawing is made with OrCAD.  The symbol is from the standard OrCAD library.)

Answer (score 1):

If the gain setting is internal and fixed, you could overlay something like "G=10" on the symbol, which would avoid misunderstanding.

I expect it would need a reference pin as well, unless it's referenced to the supply.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think so. If you using a IC you could draw a normal square with it pins. But I have never heard about an Instrumental Amplifier integrated. Are you sure you don't have a normal Opamp with some resistors around?

Comment: Oh dear, don't presume that the sum total of knowledge in your head represents the sum total of absolute knowledge.

Comment: Analog Devices has been selling them for more than 25 years....